Is it not allowed to post a link to a YouTube video in your answer?
I've posted an answer and explained all the steps in the answer. I wanted to add a short YouTube video that demonstrates the answer but SuperUser won't let me.

I add a hyperlink, put the url in and it just does not change to a clickable hyperlink like other links do. I've kept it as a normal written link and flagged my post for moderation so a mod could do this.
My post was edited, but the entire YouTube section was completely being removed by the moderator.
I can't find anything in the help section that states that YouTube links are prohibited.
What's going on here?

As I pointed out in the rejected flag on your answer, it was a link to a music video (Anthem to the Blind Harper · Aethera).
I cannot see how this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kebKKNW_O4Y) would be relevant to your answer (although it is a nice piece of music - I have it in my collection).
In addition, links to videos are not supported:


OMG. I see what happened. I copy/pasted the video, but the copy failed, and it posted an earlier copy. Yeah, the edit is justified. And... I feel so dumb now LOL

Also, I found out why the YouTube link was not working. Apparently, its a bug on SuperUser. If you post a ... line, and you press one enter, the next line cannot contain an URL, it will not parse. But if you put an empty line in between, it works.
